How to limit vertical line range in negative number field
I drew a linear graph below y=0, and now I want the vertical lines x=0.52 and x=0.75 reach the graph, not crossing the whole xy field.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(0.01,.99,99)

y = 5837.23*x - 19500

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axvline(x=0.52, ymax=-16464.6404) # ymax = y(x) result
plt.axvline(x=0.75, ymax=-15122.0775) # ymax = y(x) result

The image below is the result of the code.

I thought use of plt.axvline with ymax would stop the line at the y value, but instead it made the vertical lines rise only a little. What I want is the image below.

How can I fix it?

You can do it like this:
plt.plot(x, y)
ylim = plt.ylim() # current ylim
plt.vlines([0.52, 0.75], ymin=ylim[0], ymax=[-16464.6404, -15122.0775]) # from bottom of graph to line values
plt.ylim(*ylim) # reset to original ylim

If you read the documentation, you see that for plt.axvline:
ymin: float, default: 0
Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the bottom of the plot, 1 the top of the plot.

ymax: float, default: 1
Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the bottom of the plot, 1 the top of the plot.

so using ymax=-16464.6404 was bound to fail...
